# Ionic and WebSocket on Android

Tags: cordova, websocket, ddp

I have a meteor application running on port 3000.
 Then I have a ionic application serving a simple client.
I want to see the data adeed in the meteor application in in the ionic application.
I created a service:

```
(function () {
angular.module('myApp').factory('myApi', ['$q', '$rootScope', myApi]);
function myApi($q, $rootScope) {
    var options = {
        endpoint: "ws://localhost:3000/websocket",
        SocketConstructor: WebSocket
    };
    var ddp = new DDP(options);
    ddp.on("connected", function () {
        console.log("Connected");
        ddp.sub("allHistory");
    });

    function on(callback) {
        ddp.on("added", function (data) {
            console.log("on added", data.fields.value);
            var item = { value: data.fields.value, date: data.fields.date };
            callback(item);
        });
    };
    return {
        on: on,
    };
}
})();
```

A controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController',
function EventController($scope, myApi) {
   myApi.on(function (data) {
        $scope.history.push(data);
    });
    $scope.history = [];
}
);
```

A view:

```
 <div ng-controller="MyController" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li ng-repeat="item in history">
            <div class="row span9">
               <span>Date: {{item.date}}</span>
               <span>Value: {{item.value}}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Everything works using a web client: I can to get data from the meteor application (using the DDP protocol with the ddp.js implementation) on a web client running the command `ionic serve`.
When I try a `ionic emulate android` I cannot see the data in the AVD and I have a 'ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined' in the LogCat panel.
I tried to install the 'cordova plugin add https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android.git' but without success. How I can use websockets within a ionic application with the andorid target?

Comment: There is a sockjs implementation that simulates websockets. I added 'sockjs-0.3.4.min.js' to my scripts and replaced: 

    var options = {
            endpoint: "ws://localhost:3000/websocket",
            SocketConstructor: WebSocket
        };

with:

        var options = {
            endpoint: "http://localhost/sockjs",
            SocketConstructor: SockJS
        };

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, i got it to finally work for me, using [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs), it needs to be installed both on server and client, and instead of using this code:

```
var options = {
    endpoint: "ws://localhost:3000/websocket",
    SocketConstructor: WebSocket
};
var ddp = new DDP(options);
ddp.on("connected", function () {
    console.log("Connected");
});
```

I used this code:

```
  var options = {
      endpoint: "https://localhost:3000/echo", // echo is the prefix i set on server-side
      SocketConstructor: SockJS
  };
  var ddp = new DDP(options);
  ddp.on("connected", function () {
      console.log("Connected");
  });
```

So, now it connects. But i am now getting a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' not set thing when i deploy it to mobile, on browser it works just fine, but on the Android device it gives me this error... I can't comment on questions yet, not enough reputation, so i'm sorry to ask another question in a answer... But is there somehow i can fix this 'Access-Control...' thing?

Thank you, and i hope i helped somehow.

Comment: Maybe a tad late but you need to look into CORS. If you're sending custom headers, the server needs to explicitly "allow" those headers for a request to go through. You might have seen a preflight OPTIONS request in the console instead of or before your normal GET request.

Answer (score 0):

most probable reason to work it in browser is that your server and the browser is on same host. Try consuming the service from a different host via a browser. You'l get the same error. 
You need to allow the Headers in server side to fix 'Access-Control...' thing

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons, Android prevents sending plain text via socket. If you debug code with chrome://inspect you will see that it throws ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED error. You can establish connection with SSL or tell android to permit clear text traffic.To do this write below decleration to ...resources\android\xml\network_security_config.xml file.
(192.168.1.3 and 192.168.2.3 are socket server ip)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.3</domain>
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.2.3</domain>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
```